# Converting RSA public key from der to pub

Tags: rsa

I have a public RSA key in der format which I have to use as integration mechanism for encryption.
Problem is that when I am trying to use that key with node crypto library, it is throwing error. In the docs I am unable to find how to use der format.
While trying to convert der file to pem using openssl command -

```
 openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in m2p-test-public.der -inform DER -outform PEM -out m2p-test-public.pem -RSAPublicKey_out
```

It is throwing -

`_out
unable to load Public Key
140477267113624:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1217:
140477267113624:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:386:Type=RSA`

What am I doing wrong ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Adding output of ASN.1 decoding

`SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 rsaEncryption (PKCS #1)
    NULL
  BIT STRING (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      INTEGER (2048 bit) 
XXXXX
      INTEGER YYYYY`

Replaced numeric block with XXXX, YYYY

Comment: As I do not know much about encryption, first question I have is if it is possible to convert der to pem without private key ?

Comment: Sorry, but how to use a specific program is off-topic. Yes it is possible to convert a public key from DER to PEM without private key, and I think that openssl allows that. According to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/694445/183704), you are missing the `-pubin` command switch. It could also be that `m2p-test-public.der` is not DER. What makes you think it is? When you make a hex dump (data only) of the allegedly DER file and paste it in the [ASN.1 JavaScript decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/), what does it tell?

Comment: I have tried that already and I am getting same error.

Comment: Added the output

Comment: The ASN.1 decoding looks OK. Assuming the DER file is neither hex nor base64, I have some hope that the following could work: `openssl rsa -pubin -inform DER -in m2p-test-public.der -outform PEM -out m2p-test-public.pem` (but I did not try and YMMV).

Answer (score 2):

By default openssl is expecting a private key. As you are providing a public key you must specify `-pubin` and it will load correctly.

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in m2p-test-public.der -inform DER -outform PEM -out m2p-test-public.pem
```